# How to find appointment added with WebDav

Tags: exchangewebservices, webdav

With EWS managed API, i have to find all appointements created with WebDav. 
Which property / value I have to test to find items?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the appointment where created with WebDAV then they would have been created in Exchange 2007 or earlier and there where no properties that tell you in those versions what API was used to create the appointments. (in Exchange 2013/16 there is sever property http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{11000E07-B51B-40D6-AF21-CAA85EDAB1D0}/000B001F that does get set but this will only work for newly created appointments on that version).

Other then that The best you can do is using a Mapi Editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy and look at the properties on a one item that you want to retrieve and see if there are any candidates eg if appointments have been created pro-grammatically it maybe a static string has been used in the subject etc which you can then create a Search filter around or potentially another legacy property etc.